# AWS Location Service boto3 Error: ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-location-service

I tried to create a route with AWS LocationService. But when I run my code I get an error and I don't understand what it means…

Can you help me to understand what I did wrong?
Am I missing some credentials?

But even if I use the SearchPlaceIndexForPosition I get some information about the position. So I don't think it's a credential issue...

```
import boto3
location=boto3.client("location",region_name="eu-central-1")
response = location.calculate_route(CalculatorName='Default',
                                    DeparturePosition=[10.00759,53.54930], # Hamburg
                                    DestinationPosition=[6.95703,50.94176] # Cologne
                                    )



ResourceNotFoundException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-12586>:3
      1 import boto3
      2 location=boto3.client("location",region_name="eu-central-1")
----> 3 response = location.calculate_route(CalculatorName='Default',
      4                                     DeparturePosition=[10.00759,53.54930],
      5                                     DestinationPosition=[9.9672534, 53.54617]
      6                                     )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py:401, in ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    398     raise TypeError(
    399         "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    400 # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 401 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py:731, in BaseClient._make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    729     error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    730     error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 731     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    732 else:
    733     return parsed_response

ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the CalculateRoute operation: Resource not found
```

Comment: Did you create a “Calculator route resource” first?, according to the docs: ResourceNotFoundException:
The resource that you've entered was not found in your AWS account. 

LocationService.Client.calculate_route(**kwargs)
Calculates a route given the following required parameters: DeparturePosition and DestinationPosition. Requires that you first create a route calculator resource.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/APIReference/API_CalculateRoute.html https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/location/client/calculate_route.html